# AWS API Create instance in non default VPC with Java SDK

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, sdk

I am using Java SDK for AWS and and trying to create a service that can create/mange instances. As part of this I want to create an EC2 instance in a specific VPC (non-default). There may have more then one VPC in a zone and I want to programatically be able to create/manage instances in any of the VPC rather than just the default VPC.
Is this possible? If yes how? I looked through the API docs and could not find a way to specify the VPC at the time of creation of EC2 isntance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. In the [RunIntancesRequest](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/ec2/model/RunInstancesRequest.html) that you would pass to the EC2 `runInstances()` method, you specify the specific subnet in a VPC that you want to run the instance in.